# Select the first element of a line with python

Tags: python, list

I'm having some problems in selecting the first element of a line with python.
I have a txt file where the data are organized in this way:

```
0  3  546
1  2  435
2  4  900
22 3  384
```

I would like to print the lines whose first member matches with that of a list:

```
myList = [1, 22]
```

I've tried to do in this way:

```
for i in externalFile: 
   if i[0] in myList:
       print (i)
```

but it return to me:

```
1  2  435
2  4  900
22 3  384
```

because it finds, I suppose, a match between the "22" of `myList` and the "2" of the external file. Does someone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: I have tried your code and it prints nothing. You must have been trying something different to what you have posted. See the answer by Austin.

Answer (score 4):

This should work. Read the file line by line, check if first word in list and print.

```
lst = [1, 22] 
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        if int(words[0]) in lst:
            print(line)

# 1  2  435
# 22 3  384
```

Answer (score 0):

use `str.split` to split the line by space. And then compare

**Ex:**

```
myList = [1, 22]
with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        val = line.split()
        if int(val[0]) in myList:
            print(line.strip())
```

**Output:**

```
1  2  435
22 3  384
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to work... if I write :                                                                           
        for i in externalFile:
            if i[0] in myList:
                val = i.split()
                 print (val[0])
it doesn't print anything

Comment: it doesn't print anything

Answer (score 0):

Try the below solution, i just did a simple list comprehension, i split each line of the file by `' '` and get the first element of it and check if it starts with any of the elements of `myList` and if it is, strip it so the `'\n'` won't be in the strings

```
myList = [1, 22]
with open('test.txt') as f:
    print([i.strip() for i in f.readlines() if int(i.split(' ')[0]) in myList])
```

Output:

```
['1  2  435', '22 3  384']
```

If you want it to display it like what you wanted, try the below code

```
myList = [1, 22]
with open('test.txt') as f:
    lstcomp = [i.strip() for i in f.readlines() if int(i.split(' ')[0]) in myList]
    for i in lstcomp:print(i)
```

Output:

```
1  2  435
22 3  384
```